# Reload script in HTML from outside src?

Tags: javascript, html

Basically, I have code that looks like this in my HTML files:

```
<script src="http://somelink.something/file.extension"></script>
<script src="http://somedifferentlink.something/file.extension"></script>
<script src="http://therearelotsofthesethings.something/file.extension"></script>
<script src="http://ineedallofthesetohappeneverytimeacertaineventhappens.something/file.extension"></script>
```

I want to know specifically how to re-execute code from this kind of script whenever a certain button is pressed. I have the functionality of the button fully programmed outside of this one thing, but this script calls on outside links to specifically format everything nicely, and I need that to happen whenever the button is pressed. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Yes, I tried looking things up, but I couldn't find this exact query, nor anything that would answer it.

**EDIT:** These are mostly .js files, though not all of them are. The code that executes when the button is pressed is written entirely in `JavaScript`.

Comment: What sort of scripts are these? Are they javascript? I don't see an extension for those

Comment: Have you tried anything? You could use `document.createElement` to create script tag and add it to the head

Comment: Depending on how those scripts are written, their functionality could be available through global scope. The community could be more helpful with more specific details.

Comment: Don't write a new question, edit this question to add cmore details.

Comment: Having to reload the scripts is usually poor design. The scripts should define functions, and then you can call the functions whenever necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working code.  I used `jQuery` as my script. Use this lines inside your `onclick button event`:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
script.setAttribute('src', 'jquery.min.js');
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

And that'll do it.

**EDIT:**

Some more info.  When you do something like `script.type = 'text/javascript'` you are setting a property on the object but this is not necessarily the same thing as associating that property with an actual node attribute.